# Pandas excel like SUMIFS with two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, excel-formula

i have an excel SUMIFS that needs to translated in pandas but it seems am missing thing.

**Excel**

```
SUMIFS(C:C,$A:$A,$L2,$B:$B,$W$1)=0
```

**Pandas**

```
df[df['year'] == 2017 & df['company_id'].isin(df['company_id_2'])].sum(axis=0, skipna=True)['share_price']
```

**table**

```
   A         B            C      ...     L       ... W
company_id  year     share_price    company_id_2    2017
48299       2017        42.395        48299
48299       2016        30.82         48752
48299       2015        31.79         48865
48865       2017        24.535        49226
48865       2016        23.175        49503
48865       2015        15.7          49554
48752       2017        12.98         49697
48752       2016        15.775        50267
48752       2015        10.09         50714
```

it looks like there is an issues with second condition `df['company_id'].isin(df['company_id_2'])`. When I only `df[df['year'] == 2017].sum(axis=0, skipna=True)['share_price']` i do get the right **sum** but the second condition gives 0.0 which is incorrect.

Any help on how to construct the second condition will be very much appreciated.

**Edit**

Using each condition separately yields the correct sum but combining them does not. At least the first row should give sum `df['share_price'] = 42.395` since that satisfy the condition but i get `0.0`

Comment: What are you trying to do with `df['company_id'].isin(df['company_id_2'])`?

Comment: trying to sum `df['share_price]` where `company_id_2` occurs in `conpany_id`. So in the case above `company_id_2 = 48299` occurs 3 times in column `company_id`

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Does it matter how many times `company_id_2` occurs in `company_id`? What would the expected output be, given the table above?

Answer (score 0):

A good idea is to create a series mapping, *then* map it to your dataframe.

Here you can use a Boolean mask, then `GroupBy`:

```
s = df[df['year'] == 2017].groupby('company_id')['share_price'].sum()
```

Next, use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df[2017] = df['company_id_2'].map(s).fillna(0)
```